# Why do I not see a join in the view query?

Tags: views

I added a field to the user content type called `metro_id`.

I am trying to display that field along with the user's name in a view.  I expected to see a join in my view sql. Instead I see that everything is being selected from user table and a field has been added to the select clause: `'user' AS field_data_field_metro_id_user_entity_type`

How is this working?

Comment: Views adds that field to every query so it has easy access to the base type that the results relate to, it's nothing to do with a join on a field table. If you've added a field then you should be seeing a JOIN, yes

Comment: If the user entity is being displayed as a rendered entity so your view isn't using fields, there won't be a join in the view SQL. The view will use its query to get the user IDs then load and render them separately.